# How can I convert a class to Map[X, (List[Y], Z)]?

Tags: scala, playframework

I have `List` collection with data below:

```
case class Expense_detail(po_id: Long, supplier_id: String, price: String)

Expense_detail(1,"S00001","1000.0"), 
Expense_detail(2,"S00001","2000.0"), 
Expense_detail(3,"S00002","3,000.0"), 
Expense_detail(4,"S00003","4,000.0")
```

Is it possible to map it into below `Map` collection:

```
"S00001" -> ((1,2), "3000.0")
"S00002" -> ((3), "3000.0")
"S00003" -> ((4), "4000.0")
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes with **groupBy** an **mapValues**.

```
case class ExpenseDetail(poId: Long, supplierId: String, price: String)

val details : List[ExpenseDetail] = ...

details.
 groupBy( _.supplierId ).
 mapValues( details => ( (details.map(_.poId)), details.map(_.price.toInt).sum ))
```

This should work.
I changed the naming to honor the Scala/Java best practices to use CamelCase instead of snake_case.